# webpack loading image unexpected token

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

This is my `next.config.js`.

```
const env = require("./env-config.js");

module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
  env,
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|ico)(\?.*)?$/,
      use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "dist/[path][name].[ext]",
          },
      }
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

putting webpack setting like this disappears the compile error about not being able to load images. All good, but then, when I load the page through browser, another problem pops up

> error -
> /Users/jordan/Desktop/project/node_modules/package/dist/cjs/Frame.png:1
> �PNG
>
> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

NOTE: importing images happen on the package that side my project uses.

On the package side, I also use `rollup` and have the following:

```
const path = require('path')
const images = require('rollup-plugin-image-files')

module.exports = {
  rollup(config, options) {
    config.plugins = [
      images({ incude: ['**/*.png', '**/*.jpg', '**/*.svg'] }),
      ...config.plugins,
    ]
    // export in separate dist/esm and dist/cjs directories
    delete config.output.file
    config.output.dir = path.join(__dirname, `dist/${options.format}`)
    return config
  },
}
```

Comment: It seems like trying to parse a .png file as code. They really start with a "high", non-ASCII byte (0x89 in order to detect 7-bit transmission), and then upper-case letters PNG. And of course this is not valid JS code, hence the "Syntax Error".

Comment: Thanks for answering. which one is not valid js code ?

Comment: A .png image file is not js code. But it's trying to load it as js code.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to figure out. why ? I got the webpack config and use `file-loader`.  If I remove the webpack config in the first piece of code of my question, then compilation also fails, but putting webpack code makes compilation good, but then fails when i open the page on the browser